# Logging redirects and rewrites

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, blacklist

I'm using the following blacklist .htaccess directives in apache v2.2 (on mediatemple): http://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/

I want to get a sense of how often these directives are rejecting a request and so would like to log instances of redirection to a separate log, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Can anyone help me out?

What I've tried so far:

```
RewriteLog "logs/rewrite_log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the RewriteLog directive:

```
RewriteLog /path/to/logfile
```

More info can be found in the [mod_rewrite documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: I tried that in my .htaccess. Something like: `RewriteLog /var/www/.../log/rewrite_log  / RewriteLogLevel 3`. But the log file never appeared... could be there are no rewrites, but am running on wordpress which rewrites all the time!

Comment: It would have been useful if you included this info in your original question. Did you check if the user which is running the webserver (typically www-data) has sufficient rights to create the speicified logfile?

Comment: Hmmm. I'm running on mediatemple. The log directory is located in the root fo the domain, i.e. /var/www/vhosts/somedomain.net/logs. I assume the server can write their because other logs are there as well. Perhaps I have not specified the path correctly? But I tried the full path as well.

Comment: Relative paths are never a good idea, always use absolute paths here. Did you check if the mod_rewrite apache module is enabled?

Comment: It is. I'm running a wordpress site that cannot function without it.